# PHP - How to show last login

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I had been given a task to do some mini project. Right now I doing a registration, but I want to do last login date and time. When user login automatic date and time will update in the database. But i do not know, how to do it. I try doing like this and the time was have in the database but only show 0000-00-00 00:00:00. This was my SQL. I want the date and time been save same as my computer time. Hope you guys can help me ;)

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<?php
require "cn.php";

$name=$_POST['Name'];
$ic_no=$_POST['Ic_No'];
$user=$_POST['Username'];
$time=date("h:i:s");
$_SESSION['CurrentUser']=$user;
$pass=$_POST['Mypass'];
$_SESSION['Currentpassword']=$password;
$email=$_POST['Email'];
$mbile=$_POST['Mobile_No'];

mysql_query("insert into reg (name,ic_no, user, pass, email, mbile,time)              values
('$name', '$ic_no', '$user', '$pass', '$email', '$mbile', '$time' )");

echo header("location: sucess.php");
?>
```

Comment: Questions asking for code should **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) .

Comment: We jus t dont do it like this anymore. We decided that our data was too precious.

Comment: You should start using PDO and properly parse data before inserting it into the database. Your code above is vulnerable to SQL Injections.

Comment: Sorry guys, php new to me but i try to fast learn it. Lot of thing  i should learn it right now

Answer (score 2):

First of all change the datatype of your time field in your database, use DATETIME datatype to store date and time.

Then the basic idea is as follows:

1. User fills the login form.
2. After click on submit on the action page you should use select query using the login details like `"SELECT * FROM reg WHERE user='username' AND pass='password'"`
3. If the query return a row then fetch the id from the resultset and run a update query for the same record you just got from select query like this:
   `"UPDATE reg SET time=now() WHERE id='yourid'"`
4. Save some data in session like Id etc and redirect the user to welcome page.

Comment: Thanks @Fred -ii- to arrange my answer properly...

Comment: right now i try to follow the step then i update it back.Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save time as mysql Timestamp value, you should format it like this:

```
$now=time();
$time=date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $now);
```

Then you can always update it on user's login.

Comment: success, now the database had been save with the current date. But the time not same as my computer. Right now my time 21.02 Malaysia time, but on the database it show 13.01:02. By the way thanks ;)

Comment: Try to se default timezone by placing this above the time(); `date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kuala_Lumpur");`

Comment: success, nice thanks now i will try to used session to bring the date at homepage after login

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, please accept it with the green checkmark.

Comment: Let me try to used session first, then i do green checkmark. Maybe later want to ask something back.